# Getting Uncaught TypeError errors using Struts2 JQuery datepicker tag

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, struts2, jquery-ui-datepicker, struts2-jquery

I have a Struts 2 application with UI built using bootstrap and am trying to get JQuery datepicker working using struts2 jquery tag library. I am using `<sj:head compressed="true" jqueryui="true" />` to include JQuery CSS and JS libraries. Below is what gets included using `sj:head`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/struts/js/base/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/struts/js/base/jquery.ui.core.min.js?s2j=3.7.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/struts/js/plugins/jquery.subscribe.min.js?s2j=3.7.1"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/struts/js/struts2/jquery.struts2.min.js?s2j=3.7.1"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        jQuery.struts2_jquery.version = "3.7.1";
        jQuery.scriptPath = "/struts/";
        jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;

        jQuery.ajaxSetup({
            cache: false
        });

        jQuery.struts2_jquery.require("js/struts2/jquery.ui.struts2.min.js?s2j=3.7.1");

    });
</script>

    <link id="jquery_theme_link" rel="stylesheet"
          href="/struts/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css?s2j=3.7.1" type="text/css"/>
```

Below is the code related to datepicker in JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">From</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <sj:datepicker id="fromDate" displayFormat="m/d/y" showOn="focus" name="startDate"></sj:datepicker>
    </div>
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">To</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <sj:datepicker id="toDate" displayFormat="m/d/y" showOn="focus" name="endDate"></sj:datepicker>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {

    $("#fromDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        maxDate: 0,
        changeYear: true 
    }).attr('readonly', 'readonly');

    $("#toDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        maxDate: 0,
        changeYear: true 
    }).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
});
</script>
```

The fields are getting displayed fine and seems to be working fine as well. However, I am getting the following errors in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'version')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (viewResults:62:39)
    at j (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:776:111)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:810:100)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:865:65)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:873:97)
jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'initDatepicker')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (viewResults:360:27)
    at j (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:29948)
    at k (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:30262)
jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bind')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (viewResults:372:26)
    at j (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:29948)
    at k (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:30262)
jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'initDatepicker')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (viewResults:382:27)
    at j (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:29948)
    at k (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:30262)
jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bind')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (viewResults:394:26)
    at j (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:29948)
    at k (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:30262)
```

I cannot figure out what am I getting wrong here that is causing these errors. I tried removing the `sj:head` and instead included the libraries manually but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrong version of jQuery framework is loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/struts/js/base/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

> Don't load jQuery library twice on the same page. First time you load it with

```
<script src="... ">
```

the second time you load it with

```
<sj:head/>
```

You should include `<sj:head/>` tag in the body of the `<head>` tag.

If you use the [`<sj:head>` tag](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki/HeadTag) then you can customize it to use different version of jQuery.

Comment: Yes, I realized it and it actually was the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Upvoting the answer help others to choose right one among others that better solved their problem.